# console.log and Object.getPrototypeOf confusing message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, edge-devtools

Look the code below:

```
class Person {
    constructor() {}
}
class Passenger extends Person {
    constructor() { super(); }
}
const john = new Passenger();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(john));
```

What was printed into DevTools console in Chrome (111.0.5563.147) and Edge (111.0.1661.62) was:

[image]

Should not it be `Passenger`? with such a meaning like **the prototype of** Passenger?

Obviously, it's not a problem with the prototype itself because:

`console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(john) === Passenger.prototype) \\log true`
`console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(john) === Person.prototype) \\log false`

I guess it's just a matter of what DevTools developers have chosen to print but if so... is not it a bit confusing?

Does `Person` make any sense or I'm missing something here?

BTW Firefox (111.0.1) prints just `Object` which is pretty fair and neutral

[image]

Comment: Notably, `!(Passenger.prototype instanceof Passenger)`.

Comment: Thanks @Ry, I get it. It was just a bit confusing to me at the first glance. However Firefox seems more accurate to me, ``Object.getPrototypeOf(john)`` is just an object with its ``[[prototype]]`` pointing to ``Person.prototype``.

Comment: I don't see like a bug, just an approach which is a bit confusing with prototype objects. They are "labeling" the logged object with the immediate prototype constructor in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should not it be `Passenger`?

Well probably no. Logging `john` (a `new Passenger()`) would print an object that is "a Passenger". But printing `Passenger.prototype`? It's a hard question. The object you've logged is not an `instanceof Passenger`.

> Does `Person` make any sense or I'm missing something here?

Yes it makes some sense, `Passenger.prototype` (the object you've logged) is an `instanceof Person`, as it does inherit from `Person.prototype`. Just as if you had logged a `new Person()` instance (except that `Passenger.prototype` was never initialised by the `Person` constructor).

> I guess it's just a matter of what DevTools developers have chosen to print but if so... is not it a bit confusing?

Yes, it's their decision. In most circumstances, this approach is very useful. And yes, it is a bit confusing for prototype objects.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi! Firefox's approach looks maybe less handy but more accurate, it prints just an object, then when you expand the object in console, you see its ``[[prototype]]`` pointing to ``Person.prototype`` which is exactly what is happening.